# Why does vector::pop_back invalidate the iterator (end() - 1)?

Tags: c++, iterator, invalidation

#### Note: The question applies to `erase`, too. See bottom.

---

What's the reason behind the fact that the `end() - 1` iterator is invalidated after `pop_back` is called on a `vector`?

To clarify, I'm referring to this situation:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);

std::vector<int>::iterator i1 = v.begin(), i2 = v.end() - 1, i3 = v.begin() + 1;

v.pop_back();

// i1 is still valid
// i2 is now invalid
// i3 is now invalid too

std::vector<int>::iterator i4 = v.end();

assert(i2 == i4);  // undefined behavior (but why should it be?!)
assert(i3 == i4);  // undefined behavior (but why should it be?!)
```

Why does this happen? (i.e. when would this invalidation ever prove beneficial for the implementation?)

*(Note that this isn't just a theoretical problem. Visual C++ 2013 -- and probably 2012 too -- display an error if you try to do this in debug mode, if you have `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` set to `2`.)*

---

#### Regarding `erase`:

Note that the same question applies to `erase`:
Why does `erase(end() - 1, end())` invalidate `end() - 1`?

(So please don't say, *"`pop_back` invalidates `end() - 1` because it is equivalent to calling `erase(end() - 1, end())`"*; that's just begging the question.)

Comment: Why does `erase( begin(), begin()+1 )` invalidate `begin()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interesting question is really what does it mean for an iterator to be invalidated. And I truly don't have a good answer from the standard. What I do know is that to some extent the standard considers an iterator not as a pointer to a location inside the container, but rather as a proxy to a particular element that lives within the container.

With that in mind, after erasing of a single element in the middle of a vector, all iterators after the point of removal become *invalidated* as they no longer refer to the same element that they referred to before.

Support for this line of reasoning comes from the iterator invalidation clauses of other operations in the container. For example, on `insert`, the standard guarantees that if there is no reallocation the iterators *before* the point of insertion remain valid. *Exceptio probat regulam in casibus non exceptis*, it invalidates all iterators *after* the point of insertion.

If the validity of iterators was only related to the fact that there is an element of the container where the iterator points, then *none* of the iterators would be invalidated with that operation (again, in the absence of reallocations).

Going even further in that line of reasoning, if you consider iterator validity as *pointer validity*, then none of the iterators into a vector would be invalidated during an `erase` operation. The `end()-1` iterator would become non-dereferencable, but it could remain valid, which is not the case.

Comment: Well, if the meaning of "invalidation" is unclear, here's another way to approach the question: if I have `i2 = v.end() - 1;` `i5 = v.end();` `v.pop_back();`, would subsequently saying `i2 == v.end()` produce undefined behavior, or would it be `true`? What about saying `i5 == v.end()` -- is that undefined or is it `false`?

Comment: Just for my understanding: As we know, the Standard defines what it means when an iterator is _invalid_. Your point is, while _invalid_ is defined, the meaning of the verb _invalidate_ is not explicitly defined. Correct?

Comment: @jogojapan: Can you point me to a definition of what a *valid* or *invalid* iterator is in the standard? As far as I understand it, there is no such definition, only a some conditions that must hold true for *valid* iterators (which does not mean that they cannot also hold for invalid ones, but the standard makes no such claim)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Oh sorry. I had mentioned it in earlier comments, which apparently have been deleted meanwhile. Pixelchemist still has it in a deleted answer, but you'll find it in 24.2.1/10 (including an interesting footnote).

Comment: @jogojapan: That is hardly a definition. *An iterator **may** be singular* or it *may not*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That's not how I read it. It says an invalid iterator is an iterator _that may be singular_. That means: An iterator of which it is not known that it is not singular. (If you read it in the way you do, _any_ iterator is invalid. That wouldn't make sense.) Also, re whether it is a definition, the footnote calls it a _definition_.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Since the premise for any operation on an iterator other than destruction or assignment from a *valid* iterator is that the iterator itself is valid, the expression `i2 == v.end()` would be undefined, although I cannot see any case in which the implementation would require this.

Comment: @jogojapan: How I read it is, "an invalid iterator **can** be singular". It doesn't have to be. Futhermore, that sentence doesn't rule out the possibility that other iterators can be singular too.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Okay, so now that that's clear, the question was: *why* does the standard say `i2 == v.end()` is undefined?

Comment: @Mehrdad That would be a strange way of using English. There is a difference between "an invalid iterator may be singular" and "an invalid iterator _is an iterator that_ may be singular". The former is a statement, the latter is a definition (i.e. a statement about the meaning of a term).

Comment: @jogojapan: Yeah I think you're right actually. So an "invalidated" iterator would be "an iterator that may have become singular" right?

Comment: @Mehrdad I think so, yes. (I think the reason it says _may be_ rather than _is_ is the possibility of uninitialized iterators. Because if it's not been initialized, it must be assumed to be singular, but you can't be sure.)

Comment: @jogojapan: I think there might be a different reason -- they're trying to cover their grounds by saying that the iterator may have become singular. That is, the iterator may not have *actually* become singular when you call `pop_back`, but because that is a possibility, your only option is to assume it is singular, and proceed accordingly.

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, that's true. (My personal suspicion, though, is that they didn't think about the connection between the definition of _invalid_ and the spec for `erase()` and `pop_back()` at all, and that the situation is the result of a mistake on the part of the committee. But I obviously can't prove this.)

Comment: +1 I find your comment along with @DavidRodríguez-dribeas's answer quite plausible... Does the standard *always* ensure that "valid" iterators stay pointing to the same element throughout their lifetimes?

Comment: @Mehrdad, jogojapan: I have discussed this with ameredith this morning and here are his inputs. What is called a definition is really a requirement on the programs: *an invalid iterator must be treated as if it was a singular iterator*. That does not *define* what it is, but states how it can (or more importantly cannot) be used. There is no definition of what makes an iterator invalid, as it might depend on the implementation, but there are requirements as of when iterators must remain valid. There is a [DR](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2256) for this question.

Comment: For a different example, when inserting at either end of a `std::deque`, references and pointers to the elements in the deque remain valid, but all iterators are invalidated, on a rehash operation references and pointers to the elements in a `std::unique_*` container remain valid, but the iterators are all invalidated. There is no single definition of what makes those iterators invalid, in the first case the internal data structures could make it point outside of the container (i.e. the iterator may be singular) that is not the case of vector/unique_ containers...

Comment: I've been thinking about this for quite a while and I'm convinced you're completely right about the proxy thing. C++ really treats iterators as a way to see elements themselves, not as some way to denote locations inside a collection...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Hold your horses... Check the DR in a comment above. The committee is not that clear on the interpretation I had. The defect report is exactly the same thing that you are asking here, and it has not been disregarded.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I missed the DR, that's interesting, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

`pop_back` is usually defined in terms of `erase(end()-1, end())`.

When you erase a range of iterators from a vector, all iterators from the first erased and forward are invalidated.  This includes a range of one.

In general, a valid derefencable non input iterator always refers to the same data 'location' until it becomes invalidated.  In the case of `erase`, all non-invalid iterators afterwards have the same value *and* location currently.

Both of the above rules would have to be amended to get the behavior you want.  The first to something like 'unless you erase the last element in so doing, in which case the first erased element becomes the one-past-the-end iterator'.  And the still valid iterator will become not dereferencable, a possibly unique state change for an iterator that is, as far as I know, without precedent in C++.

The cost is both extra tricky verbage in the standard to cover your requested behavior and sanity checks for strict iterators.  The benefit -- well, I do not see one: in every situation you will have to know exactly what just happened (a very particular iterator just became one past the end instead of being invalidated), and if you know that is the case you could just talk about `end`.

And words are required.  When you call `erase( a, b )`, every iterator from `a` on will have its state changed in some way (`*a` will not return the same value, and how that changes must be specified).  C++ takes the easy way, and simply states that every iterator whose state is changed by `erase` becomes invalid, and using it is undefined behavior: this allows the maximium latitude to the implementer.

In theory, it can also allow for optimizations.  If you dereference an iterator before and after an `erase` operation, the value you get can be considered the same! (assuming no possible indirect modification of the container within object destructors, which can be proven as well).

Comment: I guess when you want the end, you have to call it fresh.

Comment: I guess I could change the title of the question to *"Why does `erase` invalidate its iterator?"*; the question is still the same: "why?" You don't need "extra tricky verbiage" to prevent this; in fact, you need fewer words -- instead of saying `at or after the point`, you just say `after the point`. Given that they don't limit the word count when making the C++ standard, I don't think "extra verbiage" was the reason why this happened. =P (If there's anything "tricky" here, it's the fact that it *does* get invalidated; it's unnecessary and, to me, counterintuitive!)

Comment: @Mehrdad Actually, if I am not mistaken, `erase()` shouldn't need to invalidate _any_ iterators except the one that was obtained from `end()` before `erase()` was called.

Comment: @jogojapan: Yeah, that's exactly the same thing as when I said `after the point` (of erasure) above.

Comment: @Mehrdad What I am saying is there is no reason to invalidate the iterators _after the point of erasure_. Only the very last iterator position needs to be invalidated.

Comment: That's for the case of `pop_back()` or `erase(end()-1, end())` but the "problem" applies to all calls to `erase`, regardless of how many elements there are and how many elements will be erased and where and...

Comment: @jogojapan: `end() - 1` is *at* the point of erasure, so `end()` is **the only** iterator "after the point of erasure", and hence it's invalidated; you're saying the same thing as me.

Comment: @Mehrdad I am of course talking about `erase()` in general, not only the case when you delete the very last element. As you said yourself, there shouldn't be any need for special verbiage for this particular exception.

Comment: @jogojapan: Are you saying that `erase(i, i + 1)` invalidates `i + 1` but leaves `i + 2` valid? That doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: @Mehrdad According to the Standard as it is, `i`, `i+1`, `i+2` and all that follow them are invalidated. But I think there is no need for that. All iterators should remain valid, because none of them becomes singular. They point to different content as elements are shifted, but they do not become singular. The only one that becomes singular is the one that was `end()` before `erase()` was called.

Comment: @jogojapan: Ah, "there is no need for that". Indeed, I agree; the only ones that should become invalidates are the ones that were originally *after* the new `end()`.

Comment: @mehrdad why do you think that would fix anything?  The state of every iterator from the start of the `erase` on changes: that state change muet be specified.  Simply removing the description of the state change does not magically make things behave the way you want them to.  As it stands, every non invalidated iterator in a `vector` refers to the exact same data after you `erase`: your plan is ... well I cannot tell, I cannot read your mind.